# Is there any reason to clone an empty array in android?

Tags: android, clone

This may seems weird, but I am currently maintaining some Android code, which uses clone of an existing **EMPTY** ArrayList, to create a new ArrayList instead of just using new to allocate an ArrayList

The code does the same when creating new LinkedHashMap(Cloning them from an empty LinkedHashMap), so it looks like something the previous developer thought about, but what do i know.

First I thought it might be a prototype/factory thing, but he cast the cloned object back to ArrayList, so I don't think it's a way to change the allocation type later.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList can be created with a initial capacity which is cloned as well, LinkedHashMap has similar parameters but this would be a weak reason.

Maybe the developer anticipated that in future versions of the code the "template" wouldn't be empty anymore.